# Azure Active Directory - Authentication without browser window

Tags: authentication, azure, single-sign-on

Is it possible to achieve Azure Active Directory authentication without going to browser window?  I will have username and password via the mobile app login interface.

I need to achieve below scenario:

1. Use open mobile application (ios/android)
2. Enter Azure AD username and password to app login screen - e.g. user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com & password
3. I pass those information to .net web service - which need to call some Azure AD api to validate user credential before proceed to perform other business logic/make database calls

Any recommendation? I DON'T want user to redirect to any login window/page as this will not be good user experience.

I have already checked few different articles but not satisfactory response yet.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe below link is helpful.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/